# iphone: local qr code generator

Tags: iphone, qr-code

can anybody suggest me some SDK or way of creating a local QR code generator for iphone? Please enlighten me on this I have referred zxing and several other qr code libraries but none of them support iphone for qr code generation

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another generator wrapped in a sample iPhone project.  This project was created in Xcode 4:

https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator

Comment: Hi Patrick, have you successfully submitted an app to Apple using the above? Thanks.

Comment: This is the script I am using in my project. But i wont let me to generate for the second time. the app crashes automatically. I dont know how to fix this

Comment: @dinesh I run the code hundreds of times in my application without fail.  Without more info, I'm unsure that I can help you though.

Answer (score 7):

here goes the solution
https://github.com/jverkoey/ObjQREncoder

Comment: I used this solution rather than the other as this is a full Objective-C library instead of a Wrapper over a C library.

Comment: very help full convert url to QR Code image in iphone sdk thanks Ankit

Answer (score 1):

The following tutorial demonstrates how you can easily generate QR Codes directly from within an iPhone app:

http://www.oscarsanderson.com/2013/08/12/implementing-a-qr-code-generator-on-the-iphone/