# QR library for MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, .net, ios, xamarin.ios, qr-code

I am trying to read and also generate QR codes (locally within application) in a MonoTouch project.

Is there any OpenSource or commercial library to read and generate QR codes for C#/MonoTouch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for reading QR Codes there are a couple of options

[ZXING.Net.Mobile](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) A MT port of [zxing library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

[RedLaser MonoTouch Binding](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/RedLaser) Is the MT binding for [RedLaser SDK](http://redlaser.com/developers/) which is a Paid SDK

And [here](https://github.com/GoranHalvarsson/BarcodeReader-MonoTouch) is a sample app using zxing.MonoTouch and MT.D

All of these are used to *read* a QR Code, i don't know any to generate QR Codes in MT, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106831/iphone-local-qr-code-generator) is a StackOverflow question that points to a couple Objc libraries which you could bind with MT